# Custom Post Type homepage template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, template-hierarchy

This is what I want: I have made a Custom Post Type in my theme and it shows in my home too, but the problem is that tha CPT takes the same elements and style of a default post in Wordpress, how I can assign a template for how my CPT is displayed at my home? When I say home I mean www.mysite.com (The content of index.php, this archive has the aspect of all the post in the home, so how I can create a dedicaded template to my CPT in the home)

Check this code example of a theme in index.php, but doesn't work for me:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php

                if ( get_post_type() == 'reviews' ) : ?>

                    <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-reviews-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                <?php elseif ( get_post_type() == 'videos' ) : ?>

                    <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-videos-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                <?php elseif ( get_post_type() == 'screenshots' ) : ?>

                    <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-screenshots-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/show-posts-frontpage.php' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>


            <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Can you try to explain a bit better?

Comment: Let's assume that I have a Custom Post Type called 'Video' and I want custom templates for this CPT. I have single-video.php (The inside content - mysite.com/video/postname) video-archive.php (For display all my 'Video' posts in one page - mysite.com/videos), but I want a template for the way that is displayed in my home (mysite.com). I hope to be clear.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your work to date.

Comment: @BradDalton This is what I want: I have made a Custom Post Type in my theme and it shows in my home too, but the problem is that tha CPT takes the same elements and style of a default post in Wordpress, how I can assign a template for how my CPT is displayed at my home. When I say home I mean www.mysite.com (The content of index.php, this archive has the aspect of all the post in the home, so how I can create a dedicaded template to my CPT in the home) Check this code example of a theme, but doesn't work for me http://www.imagebam.com/image/433e05413060466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you probably want [`get_template_part()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to load CPT specific pieces of code. For example (from the Codex):

```
get_template_part( 'nav', 'single' ); // Navigation bar to use in single pages (nav-single.php)
```

You can then reuse pieces of code on your home page, your CPT archives, etc.

[You may also find post formats useful](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats), though I am still unclear about exactly what you want to accomplish.

Take a look at the way Twenty Thirteen (for example), handles posts formats by using `content-aside.php`, `content-audio.php`, etc

Comment: I made an [image](www.imagebam.com/image/8b95ef412958801) to explain better.

Comment: The picture does not explain anything.

Comment: This is what I want: I have made a Custom Post Type in my theme and it shows in my home too, but the problem is that tha CPT takes the same elements and style of a default post in Wordpress, how I can assign a template for how my CPT is displayed at my home. When I say home I mean www.mysite.com (The content of index.php, this archive has the aspect of all the post in the home, so how I can create a dedicaded template to my CPT in the home) Check this code example of a theme, but doesn't work for me http://www.imagebam.com/image/433e05413060466

Comment: No, that won't work, but using `get_template_part()` to load pieces of code to format your CPT content will.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one home/frontpage, so I'm not sure, what are you trying to achieve...

Let's assume that your page is example.com and your CPT is books.

If you'd like to change the look of home/frontpage (the page you see when you go to example.com), then use one of these templates.

If you want to change the look of CPT index (the page you see when you go to example.com/books), then it is this CPT's archive template...

If you'd like to show books on home, then you should use `pre_get_posts` action to change main query for home...

Comment: Yeah, I want to change the look of the CPT in my home/frontpage, what template I should to use to edit that look?

Comment: Ehh, CPT is not displayed on home page by default... There is NO default template responsible for the look of CPT on home. Every option you could use is explained clearly in my answer.

Comment: This is what I want: I have made a Custom Post Type in my theme and it shows in my home too, but the problem is that tha CPT takes the same elements and style of a default post in Wordpress, how I can assign a template for how my CPT is displayed at my home. When I say home I mean www.mysite.com (The content of index.php, this archive has the aspect of all the post in the home, so how I can create a dedicaded template to my CPT in the home) Check this code example of a theme, but doesn't work for me http://www.imagebam.com/image/433e05413060466

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page template (refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/page-templates/ ). The page template code shall have a custom query to show the poats from your custom post type. Then create page named let's say 'Home'. Assign that page template to it. Then from 'Settings > Reading' Select static page to 'Home'.

Comment: Thanks for respond, but I want to change the look of a CPT when is displayed in my home (mysite.com), because for default wordpress assign the content and look of index.php to all the CPT.

Comment: To get different look you would certainly need to write custom css.

Comment: I **made** an image (www.imagebam.com/image/8b95ef412958801) to explain better.